DataFrame.apply converts integer data to float even in absence of mixed numerical types
I am using DataFrame.apply() to calculate a new "Metric" column by taking an existing integer categorical column and looking up the integer in a list, i.e., indexing into the list.  It works fine when I use list comprehension, but when I use DataFrame.apply(), I get an error saying that the integer being used as an index is not an integer.
When I set the Spyder parameter to enter debug after an error, it places the program counter on the apply statement. I queried the intermediate results and confirmed that what should be an integer becomes a float.
Here is the test code:
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

nObservations = 4 # Number of rows
nIntCategory = 4 # Number of categories in the categorical integer column
dfObservations = pd.DataFrame()

# Categorical data column
dfObservations['IntCategory'] = np.random.randint(nIntCategory,size=nObservations)
   # IntCategory
   #           1
   #           0
   #           3
   #           2

# Table to look up "Metric" value based on "IntCategory"
Cat2metric = np.random.random(nIntCategory)
  # array([0.02190873, 0.9570024 , 0.34785749, 0.13852149])

# Create the "Metric" column via table lookup in Cat2metric

# Whether to use apply instead of list comprehension
ifUseApplyNotComprehension = True

if ifUseApplyNotComprehension: # "apply" creates error in the comment below

   dfObservations['Metric'] = \
   dfObservations.apply( lambda row: Cat2metric[ row.IntCategory ] , axis=1 )
      # Index error [1]: list indices must be integers or slices,
      # not numpy.float64

else: # List comprehension creates no errors

   dfObservations['Metric'] = \
      [ Cat2metric[i] for i in dfObservations.IntCategory ]

The data is randomly generated, so it varies from trial to trial, but here is an example of what happens when I query the index row.IntCategory in the above apply loop.  It returns a float!
row.IntCategory # Returns 3.0

The apply loop can be made to work by coercing the index into an integer, i.e., int(row.IntCategory).
In this situation, why does the numerical data type change in an apply loop?  It can represent a signifcant detour to track down.
The explanations I found here, here, and here all point to upcasting if the columns contain a mix of numerical types, but that's not the situation here.
P.S. This is not a question of performance.  I've read about avoiding apply if possible.  I am seeking the most readable solution, as explained here.  Also, the code above is just for troubleshooting.  It doesn't represent the actual code that led to this behaviour.
